# How to terminate invoking setAlarm once the alarm is rang.

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

**My Problem :** `setAlarms()` method is called again and again (64 times a second!!) by the `service` once alarm starts ringing. How can I stop calling it once the alarm starts ringing?

My code

`TRTimeReminder.class`

This is the class where a new alarm can be set.

```
TRAlarmManager.cancelAlarms(this);  //cancel the the alarm is it's already set

//I have set if..else here
trDb.updateReminder(Value, title, des, date, time);  //update the database row if alarm's updated
trDb.addReminder(title, des, date, time); //otherwise add new entry in database

TRAlarmManager.setAlarms(this);  //set the alarm
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

`TRAlarmManager.class`

```
public static void setAlarms(Context context) {
    TRDBHelper trDb = new TRDBHelper(context);
    List<TRListFormat> list = trDb.getAllReminders();

    for(TRListFormat reminder : list) {
        Calendar calendar;
        Date date;

        PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, reminder);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa");

        try{
            date = sdf.parse(reminder.getDate() + " " + reminder.getTime());
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);

            setAlarm(context, calendar, pIntent);

            Log.d("parsing date", "date parsed");
        }catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("cannot parse", "failure");
        }
        trDb.close();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, PendingIntent pIntent){

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

        Log.d("set alarm called", "null");
    }
    else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
        Log.d("set alarm called", "null");
    }
}

public static void cancelAlarms(Context context) {
    TRDBHelper trDb = new TRDBHelper(context);
    List<TRListFormat> list = trDb.getAllReminders();

    if(list != null){
        for(TRListFormat reminder : list){
            PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent(context, reminder);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
        }
    }
}

private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context, TRListFormat format) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TRService.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", format.getId());
    intent.putExtra("title", format.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("des", format.getDes());
    intent.putExtra("date", format.getDate());
    intent.putExtra("time", format.getTime());

    return PendingIntent.getService(context, format.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

'TRService.class'

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TRAlarmScreen.class);
    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmIntent.putExtras(intent);
    getApplication().startActivity(alarmIntent);

    TRAlarmManager.setAlarms(this);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
TRAlarmManager.setAlarms(this);
```

from the `onStartCommand()` method of `TRService`. I believe this is what is causing the problem.

Comment: I removed it and it works now!! But a new problem arose. App doesn't cancel the alarm which is already rang. So if I set two alarms and when the second alarm is fired, it also fires the first one again. Would you please tell me how to cancel an alarm once it's rang? See my code above and please tell me what's my mistake.

Comment: If I call `TRAlarmManager.cancel(this);` from `onStartCommand()` then app stops notifying me when app runs in background

Comment: I need little more help. Please check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649349/cannot-cancel-alarm-once-its-rang